# Filter store by Id has coincidences with other store in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch

I am working in a Sencha touch app, and I am finding problems to filter correctly the next scenario:

I have this API:

In this area we have different templates number related with the Id, data is saved in a store call (for example: templates):

```
{
    "id": "0100100001",
    "templates": {
        "id": "0000000187",   ---> customerId
        "name": "TEST01",
        "validFrom": "\/Date(1360710000000)\/",
        "validTo": "\/Date(253402300799000)\/"
    },
    {
        "id": "0000000188",
        "name": "S_TEST_01",
        "validFrom": "\/Date(1360710000000)\/",
        "validTo": "\/Date(253402300799000)\/"
    }
}
```

In other Json/store called "Survey" we save the next data,

```
"id": "0000104747",
"templateId": "0000000955",
"templateName": "SURVEYAPP TEST1",
"customerId": "0100100001",
```

Question is: How can I evaluate if the `customerId` has a template created in the "Surveys" store?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Ext.getStore("Survey").findRecord("customerId",myCustomerId);`

Comment: and how to introduce this line in a "IF" ?

Comment: `if(Ext.getStore("Survey").findRecord("customerId",myCustomerId))`

Comment: sorry for my explanation (after 8 hours of work... :-( ) I am introducing values in a list and I need to filter by various parameters, firstly if the date is valid (and it´s working correctly) and if other list contains specific record, filtering by customerId and templateId in a relationship one to one.. than, if I have in a list a record contains a specified template, I cannot show in  a "template list" this template should not appears.. do you know what I mean?  thank you!

Comment: No, I don't know what you mean. Please show the code where you "introduce values in a list".